# Call to undefined method; how to fix?

Tags: php

I'm getting the following fatal error in PHP:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CoffeeModel::GetCoffeeByType() in C:\wamp\www\12.01.2015 Class 01\Coffee Website\Controller\CoffeeController.php on line 37

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0030  142264  {main}( )   ..\Coffee.php:0
2   0.0130  162800  CoffeeController->CreateCoffeeTables( ) ..\Coffee.php:15
```

The code for the above error is shown below:

```
function CreateCoffeeTables($types)
{
    $coffeeModel = new CoffeeModel();

    $coffeeArray = $coffeeModel->GetCoffeeByType($types);
    $result = "";

    // Generate a coffeeTable for each coffeeEntity in array
    foreach ($coffeeArray as $key => $coffee) {
        $result = $result .
            "<table class = 'coffeeTable'>
            <tr>
            <th rowspan='6' width= '150px' ><img runat = 'server' src = '$coffee->image'/></th>
            <th width = '75px' >Name: </th>
            <td>$coffee->name</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th>Type: </th>
            <td>$coffee->type</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th>Price: </th>
            <td>$coffee->price</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th>Roast: </th>
            <td>$coffee->roast</td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
            <th>Origin: </th>
            <td>$coffee->country</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td colspan='2' >$coffee->review</td>
            </tr>

             </table>";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

In this Code the CoffeeModel Class are present

```
<?php

require ("Entities/CoffeeEntity.php");

// contains database related code for the coffee type

class CoffeeModel
{

  //  Get all coffee types from the database and return them in an array

function GetCoffeeTypes()

{

 require 'Credentials.php';

 //Open connection and Select database

 mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die (mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db($database);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM coffee") or die(mysql_error());

 $types = array();


 // Get data from databse

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

 {

    array_push($types, $row[0]);


 }

// Close connection and return

  mysql_close();

  return $types;  

}
}

// GET coffeeEntity objects from the database and return them in an array.

function GetCoffeeByType($type)

{

require 'Credentials.php';

// Open connection and select database

mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die (mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db($database);

 $query = "SELECT * FROM coffee WHERE LIKE '$type'";

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

 $coffeeArray = array();

 //GET Data from Database

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

 {

    $name = $row[1];

    $type = $row[2];

    $price = $row[3];

    $roast = $row[4];

    $country = $row[5];

    $image = $row[6];

    $review = $row[7];


    // Create Coffee objects and store them in an array

    $coffee = new CoffeeEntity (-1, $name, $type, $price, $roast, $country, $image, $review);

    array_push($coffeeArray, $coffee);

 }

 // CLose connection and return result

 mysql_close();

 return $coffeeArray;


 }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is not clear for you from the error message?

Comment: Yes, create a `GetCoffeeByType()` method in the `CoffeeModel` class.

Comment: It's telling you the method doesn't exist. Can you show us the CoffeeModel class? Also, $result = $result . "xxx"; is redundant. Just do $result .= "xxx";

Comment: i cannot understand this error all the things are right in my perspective. i think the class or something method define type error occurs here

Comment: Yes this is coffee model class

Comment: We cannot understand it either if you don't show us the class. For all we know that method isnt in there, or it's cased differently.

Comment: Edit the question and post the code there, not in the comments.

Comment: You've got 2 answers now. both are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, focusing on only the issue posted, your problem is that you close the class after the first method:

```
}
} <---- this closing bracket is terminating the class

// GET coffeeEntity objects from the database and return them in an array.

function GetCoffeeByType($type)

{
```

Just move that one bracket to the end of the file and it should work. Next after that is to brush up on class organization but that's another story.

Comment: After moving the bracket this error has occurred              You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE 4' at line 1

Comment: Yeah cause you're missing some details in your query: `"SELECT * FROM coffee WHERE \`column\` LIKE '$type'"` - what column should be LIKE $type? and you should switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements, but for now your issue is just the query syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are closing your class too soon, after the `GetCoffeeTypes()` method:

```
  return $types;  

}
}
^ here

// GET coffeeEntity objects from the database and return them in an array.
```

You need to move that closing brace to the end of your file as now you are defining a global function instead of a class method.